# Logstash parsing data from two different filebeat inputs

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have one machine on which I have set Elasticsearch and Logstash and shipping there logs via Filebeat from another machine. I'd like to add a new machine from which I could ship logs to Logstash, parse them and store in the same elasticsearch index.

I tried to configurate filebeat on new machine with the same Logstash output but it seems logstash doesn't recieve data from multiple sources...

The logstash config file:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}


filter {

  grok { match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \[%{NOTSPACE:referrer}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)"} }

  grok { match => { "referrer" => "%{WORD:protocol}://%{WORD:domain1}.%{WORD:domain2}.%{WORD:domain3}:%{INT:port}" }

  }

  geoip { source => "clientip" }
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "my_index"
  }
}
```

Filebeat config file

```
# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The filebeat.reference.yml file from the same directory contains all the
# supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/index.html

# For more available modules and options, please see the filebeat.reference.yml sample
# configuration file.

#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================

filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  #enabled: false
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    #- /var/log/*.log
    - /var/log/hostname/proxy1/app/nginx.log
    - /var/log/hostname/proxy2/app/nginx.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*

  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #exclude_lines: ['^DBG']

  # Include lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It exports the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #include_lines: ['^ERR', '^WARN']

  # Exclude files. A list of regular expressions to match. Filebeat drops the files that
  # are matching any regular expression from the list. By default, no files are dropped.
  #exclude_files: ['.gz$']

  # Optional additional fields. These fields can be freely picked
  # to add additional information to the crawled log files for filtering
  #fields:
  #  level: debug
  #  review: 1
  ### Multiline options

  # Multiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  #multiline.pattern: ^\[

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  #multiline.negate: false

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  #multiline.match: after


#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

  # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
  #reload.period: 10s

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false

#================================ General =====================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging


#============================== Dashboards =====================================
# These settings control loading the sample dashboards to the Kibana index. Loading
# the dashboards is disabled by default and can be enabled either by setting the
# options here or by using the `setup` command.
#setup.dashboards.enabled: false

# The URL from where to download the dashboards archive. By default this URL
# has a value which is computed based on the Beat name and version. For released
# versions, this URL points to the dashboard archive on the artifacts.elastic.co
# website.
#setup.dashboards.url:

#============================== Kibana =====================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  #host: "localhost:5601"

  # Kibana Space ID
  # ID of the Kibana Space into which the dashboards should be loaded. By default,
  # the Default Space will be used.
  #space.id:

#============================= Elastic Cloud ==================================

# These settings simplify using Filebeat with the Elastic Cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

# The cloud.id setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` and
# `setup.kibana.host` options.
# You can find the `cloud.id` in the Elastic Cloud web UI.
#cloud.id:

# The cloud.auth setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.username` and
# `output.elasticsearch.password` settings. The format is `<user>:<pass>`.
#cloud.auth:

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
#output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["logstash:5045"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

#================================ Processors =====================================

# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~

#================================ Logging =====================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publish", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit output section in `filebeat.yml` like below:

```
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["Logstash_server_private_ip:5044"]
```

Logstash expects data from port 5044, not from 5045.

Answer (score 2):

Use logstash pipeline

Note: If xpack basic security not enabled username and password not required of ES (remove those lines)

in directory `/etc/logstash/conf.d`

You can write multiple conf on different port

gunicorn.log

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}

output {
  # stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx"]
       user => ""
       password => "*******"
       index => "gunicorn"
   }
}
```

access.log

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5047"
  }
}
output {
  # stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["xxxxxxx:xxxx"]
       user => "*********"
       password => "*********"
       index => "access"
   }
}
```

in directory `/etc/logstash` -> pipelines.yml

```
- pipeline.id: gunicorn
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/gunicorn.conf"
- pipeline.id: access
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/access.conf"
```

on machine - 1 in directory `/etc/filebeat` filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - "/home/ubuntu/data/gunicorn.log"

queue.mem:
  events: 8000
  flush.min_events: 2000
  flush.timeout: 10s

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash public IP:5044"]
```

on machine - 2 in directory `/etc/filebeat` filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - "/home/ubuntu/data/access.log"

queue.mem:
  events: 8000
  flush.min_events: 2000
  flush.timeout: 10s

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash public IP:5047"]
```